# Force non-flash Vimeo embed or disable Flash in a WebView?

Tags: android, flash, video, webview, vimeo

**First some details to help explain:**

If you load a Vimeo link such as the following:

http://player.vimeo.com/video/40234826, or use their iframe embed code,

into a WebView, one of two things will happen.

1. If the device has the Adobe Flash Player app/plugin installed, it will display Vimeo's embedded player. Tapping play, plays the video inline as an embed.
2. If the device does not have the flash plugin, it will display an image with a play button. Tapping play, opens the Video in a system VideoView. (Because the button links to an mp4 file.)

Since Vimeo's embedded play can be a bit buggy on the vast variety of devices available, I have found that option 2, playing the Vimeo video in an Android media player is a much better experience.

**Now the question is, how can I convince the WebView not to use Flash?**

I have tried `webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(false);` but it still loads the flash embed version. How can I trick Vimeo's player into thinking the device does not have flash installed?

Thanks

**Update** 
After further investigating, it seems that `setPluginState(PluginState.OFF)` works pre honeycomb, but this doesn't work on Honeycomb and ICS.

Comment: Hello,
I'm trying to get vimeo html 5 videos work on Froyo. How did you do that ? I have set a webchrome client and it works on ICS, but not on most Froyo device i tried.

Comment: @Ze'ev I don't believe I did sorry...